# Grid column does not work on Server

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a column in order grid whose value come from another block.
The code I used in Grid.php are as given below :

```
    $this->addColumn('sum_total', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T.Used'),
    'column_css_class' => 'a-right',
    'type'  => 'currency',
    'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    'renderer' => 'Marketplace_Mpshippingmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Sumtotal'
    ));
```

Here is the code used in block :

```
class Marketplace_Mpshippingmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Sumtotal extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
  public function input_render(Varien_Object $row)
  {
    //echo '$'.(float)($row['base_subtotal']-$row['base_grand_total']);

    printf("$%.2f", ($row['base_subtotal'] - $row['base_grand_total']));
  }

}
```

It work on localhost but make problem on server.
why?

If some one help is more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Is localhost windows? Server Linux? I can't say for certain but I ran into this earlier in the week turned out Windows is case insensitive and Linux is case sensitive. The Varien Autoloader which parses all classnames and strings was throwing in '\' where I didn't want them and magento could not find my files.

I do not know if this helps but, it was so similar to my problem I figured I would put in my 2 cents. Here was my thread with the problem explained by a much smarter person. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085012/magento-mass-action-grid-does-not-update